# Refreshing a subform from a control inside another subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have 3 forms:
frmDateRangeGeneral
frmOrderConfirmationReport
frmconfirmationStockSubform

Inside the Date Range subform I have a textbox with an event of onChange

Inside the subform frmConfirmationStockSubform I have a table which I need to requery
These two sub forms are inside one form which is frmOrderrConfirmationReport

I need to from the textbox inside a subform to refresh another subform when the event is fired; now I can trigger the event it's just referencing the subform I'm having problems with.

What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub TxtStartingDate_Change()
    forms![frmOrderConfirmationReport]![frmStockSubform].Requery
End Sub
```

Thanks for anyone who can help

Comment: You seem to pretty much have it as long as your names are correct try `Forms![frmOrderConfirmationReport]![frmStockSubform].Form.Requery` Like I said assuming he names are correct because they are different in your code than in your explanation of the Issue

Comment: Oh right; I didn't have .Form.Requery, which when I added that into the end; it worked nicely! Thanks